# Thermodynamics: System versus Ensemble

Tags: statistical-thermodynamics, monte-carlo, atomistic-simulation

In the context of thermodynamics, an ensemble is a hypothetical collection of identical copies of a system, each in a different state, used to represent the statistical behavior of the system.

That means I have to maintain a collection of systems inside an ensemble class.

In the book named [*Molecular Simulation of Fluids* by Sadus](https://books.google.pl/books?id=kVeg20PS-7kC&printsec=copyright&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false), they have `Ensemble` class but, no `System` class.

Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The textbook you refer to states (p21):

> The time-averaged properties of the real system are related to the ensemble average by ... the ergodic hypothesis.

That is, taking N snapshots of *one system* as it evolves through time (with enough time between that snapshots are not too correlated) and averaging over those is equivalent to taking one snapshot in time of N systems and taking *their* average.

Thus, both in molecular dynamics and Monte Carlo simulation, the "ensemble" is usually not an actual collection of a large number of macrostate-identical systems -- it usually refers to the equations of motion (MD) / choice of sampling moves (MC), and any modifications, needed to ensure that a single trajectory returns ergodically-consistent results with a hypothetical many-systems ensemble average.

---

EDIT, from comment: In terms of names for source code objects, we'd use `Ensemble` instead of `System` because "ensembles" refer to a set of moves that apply to *any* system, rather than a specific system. For example, MC for NPT must sample box size changes while MC for NVT doesn't. So you'd have NVT and NPT inherit from the `Ensemble` base class because they're different ensembles, while being broadly applicable across any system you want to simulate. "`System`" makes no sense as a substitute here (and it's too easily confused with other concepts -- such as the `sys` module in Python).

Comment: Okay, then they should have had a `System` class rather than an `Ensemble` class.

Comment: I _literally just explained_ what MD/MC programmers mean when we say `Ensemble`: the EOM / moves that sample one ensemble instead of another. For example, MC for NPT must sample box size changes while MC for NVT doesn't. So you'd have `NVT` and `NPT` inherit from the `Ensemble` base class because they're different ensembles. "`System`" makes no sense as a substitute here (and it's too easily confused with other concepts -- such as the `sys` module in Python).

Comment: Please, add the comment to the main answer body.

Answer (score 2):

I like how this book starts by defining all the concepts to be used after:

- [THERMODYNAMICS AND INTRODUCTORY STATISTICAL MECHANICS. Bruno Linder.  John Wiley & Sons, Inc., 2004](https://www.google.com.br/books/edition/Thermodynamics_and_Introductory_Statisti/QgzJ5Do6pfsC?hl=pt-BR&gbpv=0).

He defines `system` as:

> A system is part of the physical world in which one is interested. What is not
> the system is the environment or the surroundings. We distinguish between
> several types of systems:
>
> 1. An isolated system is a system that is totally uninfluenced by the
>    surroundings. There is no possibility of exchange of energy or matter
>    with surroundings.
> 2. A closed system is a system in which energy but not matter can
>    exchange with the surroundings.
> 3. An open system is a system in which both energy and matter can
>    exchange with the surroundings

His definition of `ensemble` is:

> During the time of measurement on a single system, the system undergoes a
> large number of changes from one microstate to another. The observed
> macroscopic properties of the system are time averages of the properties
> of the instantaneous microstates—that is, of the mechanical properties.
> Time-average calculations are virtually impossible to carry out. A way to
> get around this difficulty is to replace the time average of a single system
> by an `ensemble` average of a very large collection of systems. That is,
> instead of looking at one system over a period of time, one looks at a
> (mental) collection of a large number of systems (all of which are replicas
> of the system under consideration) at a given instance of time. Thus, in an
> `ensemble of systems`, all systems have certain properties in common (such
> as same N, V, E) but differ in their microscopic specifications; that is, they
> have different microstates.